# Pythonic method to pull the start / end of specific intervals within a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have an ordered list, for example:

```
 my_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9,
            5.1, 5.2, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 
            7.4, 7.5, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5]
```

I need intervals of numbers < 1s apart, where there are at least 3 numbers. I only want the start and end of the intervals. For example:

`Output: [[0.1, 0.4], [2.6, 2.9], [5.1, 7.5], [10.1, 10.5]]`

or

```
In[0]: print(start)
Output: [0.1, 2.6, 5.1, 10.1]
In[1]: print(end)
Output: [0.4, 2.9, 7.5, 10.5]
```

I've tried a variety of loops, but I'm having trouble getting *only* the start times appended to a new list, and also having trouble avoiding "Index out of range" when getting to the end of the list. Here is where I'm at currently:

```
    for i in range(0, (len(my_list)-2)):
        
        second = i + 1
        third = i + 2

        if ((my_list[third] - my_list[second])) < 1 and ((my_list[second] - my_list[i]) < 1):
            temp.append(my_list[i])
        else:
            end.append(my_list[second])
            start.append(temp[0])
            temp.clear()
```

My solution to get only the start of the interval is to append the items to a temporary list, append the first and last element and clear that list. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, and the list can be thousands of rows so I don't think this is a very efficient method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't the output be `[[0.1, 0.4], [2.6, 2.9], [5.1, 7.5], [10.1, 10.5]]` ?

Comment: yes you're right, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another method: numpy + list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
out = [[arr[0], arr[-1]] for arr in np.split(my_list, np.where(np.diff(my_list) > 1)[0] + 1) if len(arr)>2]
```

Or if you don't want to use numpy, you can use 2 list comprehensions to find the same:

```
splits = [0] + [idx+1 for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(my_list, my_list[1:])) if j-i > 1] + [len(my_list)]
out = [[my_list[start], my_list[end-1]] for start, end in zip(splits, splits[1:]) if end - start > 2]
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.4], [2.6, 2.9], [5.1, 7.5], [10.1, 10.5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Pandas:

```
arr = pd.Series(my_list)
arr = arr.groupby(arr.astype(int)).nth([0,-1])
result = arr.values.reshape([arr.size//2,2])
```

Or without pandas you can use `itertools.groupby` using `int` as your key: *(Note: this assumes the list is sorted)*

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for k, g in groupby(my_list, int):
    group = list(g)
    result.append([group[0], group[-1]])
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
result = [[f:=next(g), [f, *g][-1]] for k, g in groupby(my_list, int)]
```

Comment: nice use of walrus

Comment: Thank you! Also added a pandas alternative

Comment: very cool of use `groupby(lst, int)`.  Cany you explain the `int` magic here - how it works in this case?  Thanks.  +Upvote.

Comment: And what if the list has `[0.1, 0.2, 03, 0.8, 1.1, 1.2]`  got it - `[[0.1, 0.8], [1.1, 1.2]]`?

Comment: @DanielHao It's converting each value to an int. `0.1` becomes `0` and `1.2` becomes `1`. Therefore grouping by the integer representation of the floats.

Comment: Thanks @Jab to get back on the question. How about the case of `[0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.8,...]` output - seems to be off then?

Comment: @DanielHao [Works fine](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsMgEEX3c4pZKlgxzaYUehKR0NIklZqMTMwip7dW24HZvP/fj0d60drnPDEt6NPIiShs6JdInHBm2uPjAFiOIfgt4Q2t0Z0y@ly@V2j0xQHwuO2hhg4mYnwrnNGvf138bFVYklfAcjUqxpeLWVbWZvQ9xnF9Clsr1jjVyvbUOScBIpcV0boy5w8) for me.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear last time. What I mean is that `interval` returned is not really accurate in the given input case? Because there is `gap` between `0.3 to 0.8`?  Or take this input as another example: `[0.1, 0.2, 03, 0.8, 0.9]` - you will see my point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
start = my_list[:1]+[z[0] for z in zip(my_list[0:-1],my_list[1:]) if z[0]+1<z[1]]
end = [z[1] for z in zip(my_list[0:-1],my_list[1:]) if z[0]+1<z[1]] + my_list[-1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use stack to keep track of all the values that follow the condition, once new value come, then empty stack , check it has length more than 2 and if yes then add the first and last element from stack in the resultant list.

Here is another way:

```
my_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9,
            5.1, 5.2, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3,
            7.4, 7.5, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5]

result = []
tmp =[]

for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    if not tmp:
        tmp.append(v)
    else:
        if abs(tmp[-1]-v)<1:
            tmp.append(v)
        else:
            if len(tmp)>=3:
                result.append([tmp[0], tmp[-1]])

            tmp = [v]
if tmp and len(tmp)>=3:
    result.append([tmp[0], tmp[-1]])

print(result)
# output: [[0.1, 0.4], [2.6, 2.9], [5.1, 7.5], [10.1, 10.5]]
```